# Why do people in the scientific community use terminology such as renal, hepatic, and cardiac instead of kidney, liver, and heart?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, etymology, history

Why is there the need to map these everyday words onto another set of words when it seems to complicate matters?  Is it just done out of tradition, or is there some underlying logic to it?

Comment: It's an inheritance.  "The glory that was Rome"... is undeniable.  Latin derived words have been in use in science, escpecially in Medicine, for a long time.  Tradition?  I think so.  There was a time when the only version of The Bible available in Western Europe was in Latin.

Comment: If they used words we know then we'd understand them.  (Actually, it's a tradition in all sciences to use Latin-based terminology.)

Comment: @HotLicks    Lawyers do that all the time.

Comment: @Centaurus: Res ipsa loquitur.

Comment: @SvenYargs  Yes, lawyers use it ad lib.

Comment: Because, for every fact that a doctor knows which you don't know, they get paid that much more. Frankly, I'm just surprised none of the sciences have decided to switch entirely to Klingon or Ithkuil...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Renal*, *hepatic*, and *cardiac* are adjectives, while *kidney*, *liver*, and *heart* are nouns. Thus, their uses are quite different.

As for using academic terms, there is a logic behind it. Everyday words are used in everyday situations. To be more precise in your meaning, you should use more precise words.

For example, *heart* may be used in sentences such as, “You are the king of my *heart*” (a metaphorical meaning). If you use the word *cardiac*, you know you are referring to a medical topic.

Comment: It’s worth noting that terms like _kidney failure_ and _heart disease_ are compound nouns rather than uses of _kidney_ and _heart_ as adjectives. The point about precision is strengthened by recognizing that, for example, the everyday term _heart attack_ can refer to myocardial infarctions, coronary artery spasms, or demand ischemia; a speaker could even use it to refer to cardiac arrest (which isn’t really a type of heart attack). The distinction matters to the doctor who treats the patient, but not to the bystander who calls 911.

Comment: Thank you @Chris Heard. I did not appreciate that distinction.